# Referring to Memcache Objects And Updating them

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

This is a very general question regarding GAE / Java Memcache :

I have an object called Network which is stored in the Memcache , and I have another object called User which has a reference to Network .

```
Network network=Memcache.get(networkKey);
user._network=network;    //user references an object that came from Memcache...
```

now I have a bunch of code that changes user._network(without touching Memcache) :

user._network= // do some changes to the objects , without touching Memcache

Ok so here's the question , 
Looking at the code as it is , did the last line update the network object in the memcache? I have servlets that need to access the updated network object , the question is if I'm wrong by thinking at Memcache objects as regular objects .

Perhaps the right way is this ?

```
Network network=Memcache.get(networkKey);
network.doUpdate();
Memcache.put(key,network);
```

Comment: The last line doesn't do anything unless your Memcache class knows what the key is for the network obejct somehow. Memcache needs key,value.

Comment: Sorry I fixed that , that wasn't the issue just a typo . The question still stands...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter code example you provided is the correct way to update the network object in memcache, but I it will work differently than the way you expect.

Your user object refers to an instance of the network object that has been retrieved from memcache. Each time you retrieve the object from memcache you will get a different instance. And, because the instances are logically distinct from the original within the cache, as soon as the cached value is updated, those instances will become out of sync with the cached version.

For example:

```
Network network=Memcache.get(networkKey);
Network networkTwo = Memcache.get(networkKey);
user._network=network;
networkTwo.doUpdate();
// network and networkTwo are now different
Memcache.put(networkKey,networkTwo);
// user._network still refers to the initial instance of network, not networkTwo
```

You'll need additional logic in your code if you want your User objects to always refer to the version of network that is in memcache.

Comment: Thank you Dan . So just to conclude (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong..) , references to Memcached objects will not hold updated values , they will only hold the Memcached object at the time you created a reference to it . So if a programmer wants to handle and update Memcached objects references are useless (since a big part of references is that they keep track of the object as it changes . that just doesn't happen here) .

Comment: The thing to make clear is that you don't actually have a reference to the object within memcache, you have a reference to an instance of an object that was created by reading memcache. If the object stored in memcache is updated, those changes will not be automatically be reflected in any of the existing instances. So your final point is essentially correct, references to objects you've read from memcache aren't sufficient for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The code does update the Network object in memcache but references to the object in other parts of your application that already have a handle on that Network instance are not updated. Memcache stores SERIALIZED objects.

The best way to use memcache in GAE is in conjunction with something like Objectify for caching datastore objects and for storing large collections of objects that are expensive to generate. It's not well suited to storing objects that change frequently or that are used by many other objects in your application.